# optimize Apache performance mpm_prefork_module

Tags: apache, apache2

I have a VPS server that sometimes stop Apache2 because its settings are not well seized

Service specifications:
RAM 30
CPU 8

I tried to seize it myself, but I did not succeed
The current settings:
`<IfModule mpm_prefork_module> StartServers             100 MinSpareServers       20 MaxSpareServers      50 ServerLimit          4000 MaxClients           1400 MaxRequestWorkers     8000 MaxConnectionsPerChild   10000 MaxRequestsPerChild  5000 KeepAlive 0 </IfModule>`

Can you give me the best settings that suit the server specifications, knowing that it receives huge requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mod_prefork is an old module.
I advise you to use mod_event or mod_worker these module are clearly better.
You can see more information here [explanation](https://serverfault.com/questions/383526/how-do-i-select-which-apache-mpm-to-use).

About your configuration, it’s depend on you server software stack. 
If you have only Apache with maybe a Php webapp or other.
I think you can use this profile, of course with monitoring you can configure it better that my estimation.

```
StartServers             8
MinSpareServers          10 
MaxSpareServers          40 
KeepAlive                0
ServerLimit              1500
MaxRequestWorkers        1500
MaxConnectionsPerChild   4000
```

MaxRequestWorkers and MaxClients is the same directive, MaxClients is the old version.
MaxRequestsPerChild and MaxConnectionsPerChild is the same too, MaxRequestsPerChild is the old version.

Comment: Do these settings bear the requests of 1000 in the minute?
Do these settings bear the requests of 1000 in the minute?
Is it possible to use it in other mods?
What is the mod that you recommend?

Comment: That support 1500 at the same time, not minute.
If you want to user other apache mod, you will need to adapt it in function.
My configuration is only for prefork mod.
There are lots of things about it on Internet.
I hope that will help you.